# rearrange CSV columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-3.6

When the CSV file is created the columns are not in the right place as I wanted them to be. For example the column ‘'Period’ (the variable for this is ‘RD’) is the second column in the file etc. etc.

Is there a way to set the placement of each column to where I want it?

My Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import csv

es = Elasticsearch(["9200"])


res = es.search(index="search", body=
                {
                    "_source": ["VT","NCR","N","DT","RD"],
                    "query": {

                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{"range": {"VT": {
                                            "gte": "now/d",
                                            "lte": "now+1d/d"}}},

                                {"wildcard": {"user": "mike*"}}]}}},size=10)


csv_file = 'File_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d - %H.%M.%S')) + '.csv'


header_names = { 'VT': 'Date', 'NCR': 'ExTime', 'N': 'Name', 'DT': 'Party', ' RD ': 'Period'}



with open(csv_file, 'w', newline='') as f:
    header_present  = False
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source']
        if not header_present:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
            w.writerow(header_names,) 
            header_present = True
             w.writerow(my_dict)
```

Comment: Does not work like that, i have tried it

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest That's an Elasticsearch list, not a Python list. The results are JSON, so order is not preserved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries are not ordered, if you want to enforce column ordering, you need to explicitly specify that

```
import csv
headers = ['Party', 'Period', 'Date', 'ExTime', 'Name'] # Don't use my_dict.keys()
with open('header.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers)
    w.writeheader()
```

See

```
$ python sample.py && cat header.csv
Party,Period,Date,ExTime,Name
```

And when you call `w.writerow(my_dict)`, the dictionary will be ordered according to the header.

```
row = {'Period':2, 'Date':3, 'Name':5, 'Party': 1, 'ExTime':4}
w.writerow(row)
```

Outputs

```
Party,Period,Date,ExTime,Name
1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, it didn't work. i guess you will need to show me how to with my code. If you don't mind

Comment: "Didn't work" how? Errors? Not sure this answer deserved a downvote

Comment: also your code above is not grabbing the same CSV filename that i have. The file name i have is generated by current date and time.

Comment: will this conflict with my header_names and the data behind it?

Comment: Regarding the name of the file, you already have `csv_file` as the string. Just use it rather than `'header.csv'`. Are you having issues with that?

Comment: Conflict with header_names? Well, as pointed out, you don't need it. Replace it with a regular list.

Comment: could i ask you to take a look at something else for me if you dont mind?

Answer (score 6):

Using pandas its very simple:

```
import pandas as pd


# Read csv / tab-delimited in this example
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', sep='\t')

print df

   A  B  C
0  4  5  9
1  4  5  9
2  4  5  9
3  4  5  9

# Reorder columns
df = df[['C', 'A', 'B']]

print df

   C  A  B
0  9  4  5
1  9  4  5
2  9  4  5
3  9  4  5

# Write csv / tab-delimited
df.to_csv('example.csv', sep='\t')
```

Comment: keeping in mind that my CSV file name is generated with the current date and time stamp

Comment: @Rich Filenames are irrelevant to column reordering - And you can load the CSV into Pandas after writing it.

Answer (score 1):

As you are dealing with csv files it is better if use pandas for your application.

```
import pandas as pd

# Let your file have 4 columns named c1, c2, c3 and c4
# And assume you want to reorder it to c2, c3, c1, c4

data_frame = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', delimiter=',') # reading csv file as data frame with pandas

new_data_frame = data_frame[['c2', 'c3', 'c1', 'c4']] # reordered the dataframe and stored in new_data_frame

# If you want to save the result to new csv file

new_data_frame.to_csv('altered.csv', index=None)
```

In your case assuming the order of columns and delimiter is ','

```
import pandas as pd

csv_file_name = 'File_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d - %H.%M.%S')) + '.csv'

data_frame = pd.read_csv(csv_file_name, delimiter=',') # change delimiter to '\t' if needed

new_data_frame = data_frame[['Party', 'Period', 'Date', 'ExTime', 'Name']]

new_data_frame.to_csv('filename.csv', index=None)
```

Comment: how would i use this with my code above? could you show me please

Comment: What all are the column headers in your csv.? And what order you want it.?

Comment: they are listed in my code. so in my code you can see the header names so  - header_names = { 'VT': 'Date', 'NCR': 'ExTime', 'N': 'Name', 'DT': 'Party', ' RD ': 'Period'}. so the columns are Date, ExTime, Name and Party i have more but if you show me how to do this that will be good. keeping in mind that my CSV file name is a fixed name as it grabs the current date and time.

Comment: What order you really want the columns to be changed.?

Comment: for example, 'Party', 'Period, 'Date'. 'ExTime', 'Name'

Comment: I have edited the code. I haven't run the code as I am not with a working environment now. Hope that helps. Comment here if it didn't solved your issue.

Comment: Do you have pandas installed.?

Comment: I ran the code and it worked. Let me know how it went for you.!

Comment: that worked thanks! could i ask you something else to take a look on?

Comment: Happy to hear it worked. You can ask in chat as these comments are getting longer.!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157068/discussion-between-rich-and-sreeram-tp).

Comment: i have created a chat, you able to connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df  = pd.read_csv('pokemon_data.csv')`enter code here`
```

```
'Name', 'Type 1', 'Type 2', 'HP', 'Attack', 'Defense', 'Sp. Atk','Sp. Def', 'Speed', 'Generation', 'Legendary'
```

(My data frame consists of same column names in the same order)

```py
df['Total']=df.iloc[:,4:10].sum(axis=1)
```

```
`'Name', 'Type 1', 'Type 2', 'HP', 'Attack', 'Defense', 'Sp. Atk','Sp. Def', 'Speed', 'Generation', 'Legendary', 'Total'`
```

(adding a new column Total which is the sum of hp, attack, defence, sp.atk, sp.def,speed)

```py
cols = list(df.columns.values)
df = df[cols[0:4]+[cols[-1]]+cols[4:12]]
```

```
'Name', 'Type 1', 'Type 2','Total', 'HP', 'Attack', 'Defense', 'Sp. Atk','Sp. Def', 'Speed', 'Generation', 'Legendary'
```

(Moving the 'Total' columns)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.